# DataTables 1.9.4 disable sorting for specific row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i'm using DataTables 1.9.4

table

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="example">
              <thead>
                <tr><th>Date</th><th>Discription</th><th>Amounts</th><th class="no-sort">Edit</th></tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="no-sort"><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Starting money</td><td>$500</td><td>edit</td></tr>
                <tr><td>2013-08-25</td><td>Payment out</td><td>-20</td><td>edit</td></tr>
                <tr><td>2013-08-26</td><td>a Given money</td><td>-80</td><td>edit</td></tr>
                <tr><td>2013-08-27</td><td>Fees taken</td><td>-100</td><td>edit</td></tr>
                <tr class="no-sort"><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Balance</td><td>$300</td><td>edit</td></tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

and i'm trying to get the first and last row  not to sort and the edit column not to sort with this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
                 "oLanguage": {
                  "sZeroRecords": "No records to display"
                 }
            });
            var $tr = $('#example tr.no-sort');
            var mySpecialRow = $tr.html();
            var opts = {};
        opts.fnDrawCallback = function(){
            $('#example tbody').prepend(mySpecialRow);
            };
            });
```

But it not working still those rows are sorting, i have searched every where can any one please help , thanks

Comment: Have you tried this http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/

Comment: This is not for my case

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to add one more row in thead and one row in tfooter which will not sort might be it help.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Discription</th>
<th>Amounts</th>
<th>Edit</th>
</tr>
<tr class="no-sort">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Starting money</td>
<td>$500</td>
<td>edit</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>             
<tr>
<td>2013-08-25</td>
<td>Payment out</td>
<td>-20</td>
<td>edit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2013-08-26</td>
<td>a Given money</td>
<td>-80</td>
<td>edit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2013-08-27</td>
<td>Fees taken</td>
<td>-100</td>
<td>edit</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfooter>
<tr class="no-sort">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Balance</td>
<td>$300</td>
<td>edit</td>
</tr>
</tfooter>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should place the the last row in a 'tfoot' element (You have used tfooter instead). It will prevent sorting

Comment: This could be a comment